# Setting autoHeight on vbox doesn't set height

Tags: extjs

I am using ExtJs 3.4.0.

I have a problem with autoHeight property and layout: 'vbox'.

I would expect that setting autoHeight: true will automatically set height of vbox for all containing elements. But, none of the elements is visible. They become visible only if I set height to some number, like height: 400. Is it possible to set autoHeight property on vbox?

My code is [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/38f9)

```
Ext.onReady(function () {

    var panel = new Ext.Panel({
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        height: 400,
        items: [{
            layout: 'vbox',
            autoHeight: true,
            height: 'auto',
            items: [{
                layout: 'form',
                items: {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'first test'
                }
            }, {
                layout: 'form',
                items: {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'second test'
                }
            }]
        }]
    })

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have forgotten the parent element layout:
[image]

```
Ext.onReady(function () {

    var panel = new Ext.Panel({
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        height: 400,
        layout: 'fit', // This is forgotten. 
        items: [{
            layout: 'vbox',
            items: [{
                layout: 'form',
                items: {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'first test'
                }
            }, {
                layout: 'form',
                items: {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'second test'
                }
            }]
        }]
    })

});
```

Comment: You are right. But I don't understand why I have to provide height: 400 for main panel? It seems that layout: 'fit' works only on subelements of the main panel, not on main panel itself.

Comment: Layout always works on sub element. What exactly do you need? The sample you have provided has some strange layouting..

Comment: By the way, the ExtJs 3.4 is > 7 (seven, Release Date: March 29, 2013) years old. Why don`t you upgrade your project to a little bit new version? ;)

Comment: Good question - as far as I know extjs is not backward compatible. That means I can not be sure how many things will be broken because of version upgrade. Project is huge, a lot of controllers / views.